# What is the best way to represent heavy hash decryption for a hacker movie?

Tags: hash, decryption

As a school project, I'm making a video about hackers across the time and there is this one scene where my character enter a big hashed key in a linux based terminal and I need to visually represent the fact that this key is being decrypted.

So, what I'm looking for is something to display in the terminal to represent that. I need this to be very verbose (to give that hollywood effect of line scrolling in the terminal) and it has to be real (or as true as possible).

If you have any idea of where can I find those kind of logs or a way to generate them (maybe a exiting decryption program with verbose mode activated ?)

Comment: By definition, a hash value cannot be "decrypted". Please, if you want it to look realistic, first get your terminology straight. Only an absolute n00b would refer to "decrypting" a "hash".

Comment: I think the hashcat tool might be able to do what you want

Answer (score 1):

To keep real I'd go for john the ripper. Holding any key will result in displaying current status. Also, remember that it's not possible do decrypt a hash since it's a one way function.